# Java 8 Stream filter to filter specific portion of a file

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have a file with too many information. Like,

```
AA BB CC DD 
WW FF SS FF
..
..
..
```

and then,

```
**** Input data ***
**
*
142.12123  Input taken for metrics
123.1222   Calculation point
.
.
.
**** Another Input ****
```

Is there a way to pick only from

> Input data

till before

> "Another Input"

I tried to read the file as Stream and filter,

```
Stream<String> output = Files
                .lines(Paths.get("a.out"))
Map<Boolean, List<String>> partition = output
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.contains("Input data")));
```

but the filter appears to be filtering only one row. Can we filter multiple rows or set from to end?

Comment: You could try to use a flag that you set to true once you find `Input data` and to false after `Another Input`, that flag would be evaluated in the filter to get that block. But there is probably simpler solution.

Comment: You’re filter predicate matches one row. How do you expect your code to magically work?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm pretty new to this Streams and collectors, just want to check how to set the end parameter or the simple solution.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar look at my answer, this way you can make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a java 9 stream api `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`, which take a predicate as an argument.

```
takeWhile(s->s.contains("Another input"))
.dropWhile(s->s.contains("Input data"))
```

You can achieve simillar result using **java 8** and filter:

keep in mind, it will work only in ordered stream, and parallerism will break this code.

Note that I have no IDE where I currently am, so I am not sure that this one will compile, but when you fix errors it should work.

```
 Stream<String> output = Files
        .lines(Paths.get("a.out"))
    List<String> partition = output
        .filter(new StartData())
        .filter(new EndData())
        .collect(toList);
class StartData implements Predicate<String> {

  boolean matchingData = false;

  boolean test(String input) {
    if (input.contains("Input data")) {
      matchingData = true;
    }
    return matchingData;
  }
}
class EndData implements Predicate<String> {

  boolean passThrough = true;

  boolean test(String input) {
    if (input.contains("Another Input")) {
      passThrough = false;
    }
    return passThrough;
  }
}
}
```